# clear data from a row in a table html

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

hi there I want to clear the data from a table but just one row and not delete the row. i was looking for some code  but I find just delete row
what is the best way to clear the data from a `tr` and leave the td `tittle` just clear the Item and Task

```html
<link href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.1.min.js"></script> 
<script src="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

   
    
<table id="table" class="table table-bordered">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th></th>
      <th>Task</th>
      <th>Item</th>
      <th></th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
  <tr>
  <td>tittle</td>
  <td data-name="task" class="task" data-type="text">task1</td>
  <td data-name="Item" class="Item" data-type="select">Item2</td>
  <td>  <button id="delete" class="btn btn-sm btn-default">delete data</button></td>
  </tr>
    <tr>
  <td>tittle</td>
  <td data-name="task" data-disabled="true" class="task" data-type="text">task2</td>
  <td data-name="Item" data-disabled="true" class="Item" data-type="select">Item1</td>
  <td>  <button id="delete" class="btn btn-sm btn-default">delete data</button></td>
  </tr>
   <tr>
  <td>tittle</td>
  <td data-name="task" class="task" data-type="text">task3</td>
  <td data-name="Item" class="Item" data-type="select">Item3</td>
    <td>  <button id="delete" class="btn btn-sm btn-default">delete data</button></td>
  </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Clear 2nd row: `$("#table tr:nth-child(2) td").empty();`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On click find the [`.parent()`](https://api.jquery.com/parent/)  of the button, and clear its [`.siblings()`](https://api.jquery.com/siblings/#siblings-selector) using [`.empty()'](https://api.jquery.com/empty/):

```js
$('#table').on('click', '.delete', function() {
  $(this).parent('td')
    .siblings('.task, .Item') // or remove selectors to clear all siblings
    .empty();
});
```

```html
<link href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>



<table id="table" class="table table-bordered">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Id</th>
      <th>Task</th>
      <th>Item</th>
      <th></th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>1</td>
      <td data-name="task" class="task" data-type="text">001</td>
      <td data-name="Item" class="Item" data-type="select">Item2</td>
      <td><button class="delete btn btn-sm btn-default">delete data</button></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>2</td>
      <td data-name="task" data-disabled="true" class="task" data-type="text">002</td>
      <td data-name="Item" data-disabled="true" class="Item" data-type="select">Item1</td>
      <td><button class="delete btn btn-sm btn-default">delete data</button></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>3</td>
      <td data-name="task" class="task" data-type="text">003</td>
      <td data-name="Item" class="Item" data-type="select">Item3</td>
      <td><button class="delete btn btn-sm btn-default">delete data</button></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: work great and how can I clean just the `td` Task and Item

Comment: @MoteCL - by adding selectors to siblings. See updated answer.

Comment: Thanks a lot my budda!

Answer (score 0):

If you want to remove the row entirely :

```
$('#delete').click(function() {
    $(this).closest('tr').remove();
});
```

To remove all content -including `th` divs- :

```
$('#delete').click(function() {
    $(this).closest('tr').empty();
});
```

To remove only the content of each cell :

```
$('#delete').click(function() {
    $(this).closest('tr').children().empty();
    $(this).closest('tr').css({display: "hidden"});//to visually remove the line (and not have an empty line)
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$("#table tr:nth-child(n) td").empty();
```

OR

```
$("#table tr:nth-child(n) td").html('');
```